# LaTeX Package Manager/Installer similar to npm (js node modules) which install PKGs per project and fix versions

Tags: packages, installing, ctan, tlmgr

I have been too often in package dependency hell in LaTeX:  I have several LaTeX projects on my system and all use the same installation of TeX Live. Changes to the system/user wide installation can affect all existing projects. Luckily, the tex kernel is stable but packages change and can break other packages or your own code which I have encountered both.

Now I avoid any updates to my LaTeX installation and be anxious about any system wide TeX Live upgrade.  However, I cannot use new possibilities or fixes introduced with newer package versions.

Therefore, I would like to install packages per project and freeze their version per project. This allows me to use new package versions in new projects without affecting my whole system.

I have encountered package manager for other software environments such as

- [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for [php](https://www.php.net/) packages
- [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/) for JavaScript node modules
- [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/) for [python](https://www.python.org/) packages

which makes installing packages per project fast and easy. Actually, they install by default per project and create typically two files per project

1. a file listing dependencies and version ranges (e.g. composer.json, packages.json, Pipfile)
2. a lock file which fixes package versions (e.g. composer.lock, packages-lock.json, Pipfile.lock). This allows to install the project on a fresh system with the exact same package versions known to work.

Is there a package manager or a project for LaTeX packages which works similar?

Afaik, ctan.org does not store the history of packages. Is this correct?

Comment: There is ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive that contains old versions of TeX Live. Each version also has a package repository that is frozen, for example ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/tlnet-final/archive/ for packages as per April 14th 2016. However I don't think there is a package manager that has your requirements (i.e., specify the exact package version to be installed).

Comment: I thought that `latexmk` might help, but I didn't find the variable that might points to a different path when compiling a project.